# MPMoviePlayerController black screen on loginview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to use the library https://github.com/arturfelipet/AnimatedLogin

I created my own project and wrote exactly the same code as in their example (but in my project I used Storyboard), but the video only shows a black screen. Here's the way I create the **MPMoviePlayerController**:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController () {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    NSURL *movieUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"background"  withExtension:@"mp4"];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    player.view.frame = screen;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [self.player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playVideo)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification
                                               object:player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.player];

    [player play];
}

- (void)moviePlayerDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note.object == self.player) {
        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            [self.player play];
        }
    }
}

-(void)playVideo{
    [player play];
}

@end
```

But it's only a black screen when the app shows up. I'm using this code in my LoginViewController which presents from App Delegate like this:

```
if (![PFUser currentUser])
        self.window.rootViewController = [UIStoryboard instansiateVCWithClass:[TPLoginViewController class]];
```

Maybe it has to do something with that? I've  tried so many things and would really appreciate an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you doing all initializing in your `viewDidLoad`. Which means that processing will block your screen until all the task are done completely.

Put that code in a method and call it after delay using:

```
[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];
```

**EDIT:** As turned out after checking with @tracifycray, there was some problem with URL,it was turning out nil somehow. As he said, "Yes, I got it to work. I tried to use a .mov-file instead, and then it worked".

Comment: So I tried to put it in a function: -(void)moviePlay, and then, in viewDidLoad I tried: [self performSelector:@selector(moviePlay) withObject:self afterDelay:2]; But it only shows a white screen for 2 seconds, and then the black screen. @rptwsthi

Comment: Do you have any ideas? @rptwsthi

Comment: @tracifycray May be your URL is making issue. it returns nil.

Comment: Yes, I got it to work. I tried to use a .mov-file instead, and then it worked.

Comment: @tracifycray Perfect! :)